Proof assistance: show that $y < F(x)$ is equivalent to $F^{-1}(y) < x$
Exercise:
For a distribution function $F : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$, let
$$F^{-1} : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \quad u \mapsto \sup \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid F(x) \leq u \}$$
be the generalized inverse of $F$.
Let $U$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Show that the random variable $Z := F^{-1}(U)$ has the distribution function $F$.
Important note
note that I am working with the definition which states that the CDF is left-continous and not right-continous.
Question:
I know how to prove it once one has established $F^{-1}(y) < x \iff y < F(x)$ but this is a non-trivial statement that needs to be shown beforehand.
In order to not overkill the post I will first give only one direction of my "proof" and would be happy to get some assistance here:
so we need to show that
\begin{align}
y < F(x) \implies F^{-1}(y) < x \\ 
F^{-1}(y) = \sup\{a \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ F(a) \leq y \} \leq x ;
\end{align}
at first we only know that at least $\leq$ since the CDF is non-decreasing.
My idea is now to say: "Ok, if there would be the equality then $x$ would've been the supremum but this would mean $F(x)\leq y$ and we know that $F(x) > y$. Contradiction."
Thus, $F^{-1}(y)= \sup\{a \in \mathbb{R} \ | \  F(a) \leq y \} < x.$
Does this make sense or am I missing a lot?

You are just using left-continuity to say that $F(x) \le y$. So your argument is fine.
